# How can we call a visualforce page on creation of a record

Tags: apex, visualforce, process-builder, visual-workflow

I want to perform a synchronous web service callout on inserting a record into Salesforce neither trigger nor process builder is supporting synchronous web callouts so I thought of redirection to a visualforce where i can do a callout in its constructor so how can i redirect to a visualforce page on inserting a record

Comment: How you are inserting the record

Comment: explain more about why the outbound call needs to be synchronous -- especially since SFDC doesn't allow DML to occur before a callout in the same transaction.

Comment: Actually we are using a managed package in which a record is being created in salesforce so on its creation i need to send this to a rule engine to process the input and return a output depending on which i need to process the further steps

Answer (score 1):

A record can be Inserted via API, VF page, Data loader and what not. So redirection thing aint gonna work if there is no UI via which record is inserted.

If you Have a VFPage or lightning component you can achieve this by using JS.

There is a limitation in salesforce that you cannot do a callout after DML. Thus after your insert there is no way you can do a callout via native SF. So you have to use JS

1. Step 1 : Insert the record and return its ID via remoting/aura method
2. Step 2: Use the Id in JS and do a callout using another remoting/aura method.

you can use Javascript callbacks to queue one method after another, so it would look like 1 transaction to end user but it is 2.

Are there any other hacks?

1. Workflow Outbound Messages: There are quite good as you are firing after record insert
2. Future Method: You can invoke a Future method from trigger that will do a callout for you.
3. Queueable: You can queue the callout after the insert operation and the callout will be near realtime
4. Invocable method: From process builder call invocable method which will in turn call Future/Queue method for your call.